# WILL reinstalling using custom method of WINDOWS 10 delete all my drives?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I am Currently Reinstalling windows10 64bit from 64 only . But i am not sure if my hard drives will get deleted. I have 3 hard drives.

LOCAL DISK C , D , E. **In local disk C i have my windows installed previously.** Now reinstalling windows 10 will give me an option of UPGRADE AND CUSTOM. 
I dont want to lose data on my D and E drive.

**Q1** : What shall i choose CUSTOM OR UPGRADE so that i reinstall windows 10 with only deleting my  **C DRIVE**?

**Q2** : After reinstallation will i have to download

```
     1:ETHERNET DRIVER?
     2:AUDIO DRIVER?
     3:USB DRIVERS?
```

**Q3** : IF SO then how will i download?

Comment: If you know what you're doing and correctly select the partition corresponding to C, nothing will happen to the other partitions. But in any case you should have backups.

Comment: Q2 is unanswerable without knowing your hardware specifications, obviously. But you should download all the drivers from the manufacturer before reinstalling anyway. And it's another, different and unrelated, question. Please ask only one question. If you have another please post it as another question.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i thought the second question was related to it. As the first thing any user will do after reinstallation is download drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia u said that correctly select the partition corresponding to C. But before that i have to select CUSTOM? if so then i will select partition corresponding to c then delete? And the others will stay same?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It will not delete the partition, it'll format it. With the "upgrade" option it'll keep most of the things.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  which is better if change from a old motherboard to a new mobo which has UEFi bios or if i want my pc to boot fast and lag free. UPGRADE OR CUSTOM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94169/discussion-between-saumyojit-das-and-gabrielagarcia).

Answer (score -1):

> Q1 : What shall i choose CUSTOM OR UPGRADE so that i reinstall windows 10 with only deleting my C DRIVE?

Choose Upgrade - this option is only available if Windows has located the current
installation, so it will only overwrite it, without touching the other drives.

> Q2 : After reinstallation will i have to download

Nothing - **if** you plan ahead and backup the existing drivers.

Use a free product from the article
[Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm)
to backup the drivers.

The drivers will most likely be stored one per folder and can be reinstalled from
there. Don't store them on the C drive.

Windows 10 is very good on drivers, so it will likely identify correctly most
of the devices. Only install drivers for the ones that malfunction or have
a yellow question-mark icon in Device Manager.

> Q3 : IF SO then how will i download?

Question answered above.

It would be a good idea before starting to take an image backup of the
C disk in a format that can be restored, just in case.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: what with the custom option . I will choose that and then how can i delete only c drive ? **There will be a option where to install windows?? then i will format the drive which is c** and then procced . Am i right?

Comment: An upgrade will just list the operating system that it finds, which will be on C. You don't need to choose the disk - this is automatic.

Comment: I am asking about custom not upgrade.

Comment: Custom is risky. The chances are that it will detect the existing Windows installation and will upgrade it, but nothing is sure. But as to your question: Custom will ONLY use the disk you specify, absolutely no other disk will be destroyed.